# Utgent issue - Can't print pdf and cant package slips on live server

Tags: magento

I have problem with live server . When I print invoices or anything in pdf format than it gives error that not a proper format or Corrupted file.So On live I can't download pdf for invoices or packageslips..So any server configuration required ????

Comment: So urgent that you didn't even have the time to spell "utgent" correctly...

Comment: Hint: feeding us with the sense of urgency never helps reception. Either we can answer, or we can't. It this case, I'd say we can't.

Comment: Note that this isn't even on-topic here as this is not a programming question.

Comment: which version of magento are you using?

Answer (score 1):

fix it by commenting out `__construct` and `__destruct` in `lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php` you issue will fixed.

```
`//    abstract public function __construct();

/**
 * Object destructor. Closes the data source.
 *
 * May also perform cleanup tasks such as deleting temporary files.
 */
//    abstract public function __destruct();`
```

Hope will help!

Comment: Commenting/Removing a core code can't be a solution

Comment: @DushyantJoshi, If there is issue with core zend library, there there is two option, either update whole library or fix the issue in core file. So, I think fixing issue in core file is more suitable. http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12093

Comment: Thats good you shared a link

Answer (score 0):

Parul, it's bug of Zend not the magento. So you have to go to the library of zend and comment the constructor and destructor of the class.

You need to go to  lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php  of your root folder and open the file and comment `//abstract public function __construct();` on line 78 and go to line 85 and comment `//abstract public function __destruct();`.